# Cypher Pattern Matching

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, cypher

I am attempting to match the pattern below in Neo4j using Cypher and am in need of some help.  My goal is to find the name of the B nodes (can be one or more) that do not have A nodes associated and the A node names on either end are the same. I also need to identify the shortest path only.  As a result I need the list of B node names and the A node name that is on both ends of the A node gap.

Can anyone help me with the query to get these results?

Your help in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Pattern to Match:

[image]

Comment: What does "on both ends of the A node gap" mean? And can you give an example of the result you expect for your sample data?

Comment: In the linked image there are B nodes that do not have relationships to A nodes creating a gap.  The result would be A.Name, B.Name.  A.Name being the name of the A node that is matched on either end and B.Name is the name of each B node that does not have a relationship with an A node in this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

This might be what you are looking for:

```
MATCH (a1:A)<--(b1:B)
MATCH p = SHORTESTPATH((b1)-[*]->(a2:A))
WHERE
  LENGTH(p) >= 3 AND
  ALL(x IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE 'B' IN LABELS(x))
RETURN a1, a2, NODES(p)[1..-2] AS bs;
```

*NOTE: Depending on your actual data, you may need to put a reasonable  upper bound on the variable-length `SHORTESTPATH` search in order for the query to finish in a reasonable amount of time (or at all). For example, to limit the maximum path to a length of 10, you could use `[*..10]` instead of `[*]`.*

With sample data that looks as follows:

[image: Test Data]

I get this result:

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│a1     │a2     │bs                            │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│{id: 1}│{id: 2}│[{id: 12}, {id: 13}]          │
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{id: 1}│{id: 3}│[{id: 12}, {id: 13}, {id: 14}]│
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{id: 1}│{id: 4}│[{id: 12}, {id: 13}, {id: 14},│
│       │       │ {id: 31}, {id: 41}]          │
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{id: 2}│{id: 4}│[{id: 31}, {id: 41}]          │
├───────┼───────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│{id: 3}│{id: 4}│[{id: 41}]                    │
└───────┴───────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When i type in the query I get the following warning:

Exhaustive shortest path has been planned for your query that means that shortest path algorithm might not be used to find the shortest path.  Hence an exhaustive enumeration of all paths might be used in order to find the requested shortest path.  Using shortest path with an exhaustive search fallback might cause query slow down since shortest path graph algorithms might not work for this use case. ...

Comment: cont.  It is recommended to introduce a WITH to separate the MATCH containing the shortest path from the existential predicates on that path.

When I run the query it runs for several hours then errors out.  The log says the client discontinued the query but it seems that it timed out.

I did run the query with a limit 10 on it and it returned results.

Comment: Yes, variable-length searches can always take too long to finish, depending on the actual data. I have edited my answer with a note about this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in a reasonable amount of time using APOC Procedures' [path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths).

Assuming that we are only interested in the :B nodes along the shortest path from an :A node to only the next reachable :A node following a single relationship direction (between :B nodes), we can use the path expander to find the nearest :A node for each :A node, then filter for the nodes in that path that don't have a direct relationship to an :A node.

```
MATCH (start:A)
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(start, {relationshipFilter:'FOO>|BAR', labelFilter:'+B|+A|/A', limit:1, filterStartNode:false}) YIELD path
WITH start, last(nodes(path)) as end, [node in nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE NOT (node)-[:BAR]->()] as gapNodes
WHERE size(gapNodes) > 0
RETURN start, gapNodes, end
```

Note that this does not return the :B nodes that are in the longer path between A1 and A2, as you mentioned you wanted nodes on the shortest path only.